Number of non-equivalent irreducible representations of a finite group $G$ over an arbitrary field $F$/non-isomorphic simple $F[G]$-modules
in my algebra class, they give us as an exercise to prove that a finite group $G$ admits at most finitely many non-equivalent irreducible representations over an arbitrary field $F$.
Now, I showed that the number of non-equivalent irreducible representations of $G$ over $F$ is equal to the number of non-isomorphic simple $F[G]$-modules, where $F[G]$ denotes the group algebra of $G$ over $F$.
Also, I know that a consequence of Maschke's Theorem is that the statement above holds when $F$ has characteristic $0$ or not dividing $|G|$. However, here we look for an argument that could work for any $F$.
I believe the sense of the exercise was essentially proving the equivalence between simple $F[G]$-modules and irreducible representations (indeed it is a class in Group Theory). So the point is actually why there are finitely many such modules?
I know there are only finitely many non-isomorphic simple modules over semisimple ring. However, at the best of my knowledge $F[G]$ is a priori just Artinian. I cannot find any evidence in the literature about this specific case.
I would appreciate any suggestion, or reference that you can provide, thank you.

They are all quotients of $F[G]$.

Thank you. I imagine you refer to the fact that any simple module $M$ is cyclic, so there is some $m\in M$ s.t. $M=F[G]m\cong F[G]/Ann(M)$ by the Fundamental Isomorphism Theorem. However, I don't see why this provides the thesis: can you give some more details please?

Have you tried to use the Artinian property?

No, no more details! You have given this as an exercise, so you should do it yourself. Remember $F[G]$ is finite dimensional, so how could it have infinitely many non-isomorphic quotients?

@Derek: I don't know if that last sentence is specifically meant to allude to the argument I gave or if it is some general heuristic, but I don't think the general heuristic holds. Even a finite-dimensional vector space has infinitely many subspaces, and for example I think finite-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebras can have infinitely many non-isomorphic quotients.

Actually I think even finite-dimensional algebras can have infinitely many non-isomorphic quotients, e.g. quotients by ideals contained in the Jacobson radical.

@QiaochuYuan OK, it is not hard to show that a direct sum of pairwaise non-isomorphic irreducible $F[G]$-modules is generated by a single element, i.e. any element that projects non-trivially onto each of the summands. So such a module is a quotient of $F[G]$ and hence must have finite dimension.

No specific property of the group algebra is needed beyond that it is finite-dimensional:

Proposition: If $A$ is Artinian then there are finitely many isomorphism classes of simple $A$-modules. Furthermore, if $A$ is a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $K$ then there are at most $\dim_K A$ isomorphism classes of simple $A$-modules.

Proof. Recall that the Jacobson radical $J(A)$ is the intersection of the annihilators of all simple $A$-modules, so simple $A$-modules are in natural bijection with simple $A/J(A)$-modules. Now the key observation is that since $A$ is Artinian, $A/J(A)$ is semisimple (see e.g. here). So by the Artin-Wedderburn theorem it is isomorphic to a finite product
$$A/J(A) \cong M_{n_i}(D_i)$$
of matrix rings over division rings, and has one isomorphism class of simple module for each matrix ring. So there are finitely many. If $A$ is finite-dimensional over a field $K$ then the dimension of each algebra on the RHS over $K$ is at least $1$ so there can only be at most $\dim_K A$ of them (and this bound is sharp iff $A \cong K^n$). $\Box$

Hi, thank you very much for your comment. I'm trying to understand the last two lines of your answer (RHS stands for "right-hand side" right?): can it be as follows?
Since $R=A/J(A)$ is semisimple, there are only finitely many simple $R$-modules (each of which is isomorphic to one of the $M_{n_i}(D_i)$'s). Any simple $A$-module $N$ is cyclic, so there is a composition of epimorphisms $N\rightarrow A\rightarrow R$ which sends $re\mapsto rJ(A)$, with $e$ generator of $N$. Now, whenever $N$ is non-trivial, nor is this map. So, by simplicity $N$ must be isomorphic to one of the $M_{n_i}(D_i)$.

@F. Salviati: I'm not sure what you're trying to establish with most of this argument. That last statement about simple modules is not true ($M_2(K)$ is already a counterexample) but it's also not necessary for anything. RHS stands for right-hand side, yes.

I was just trying to prove that any simple $A$-module is also a simple $A/J(A)$-module to complete the proof, but as you correctly pointed out, my previous comment is wrong.

I added a more detailed argument as an answer in the following, I hope it could help someone else. I realized that I wasn't able to conclude the argument in the first place because we had a different definition of Jacobson radical (as the intersection of maximal two-sided ideals, instead of one-sided), and then I couldn't conclude the inclusion $J(A)\subseteq Ann_A(M)$ for a simple $A$ module. Thanks a lot!

@F. Salviati: the definition of the Jacobson radical that's suited to making that argument is that it's the intersection of the annihilators of the simple modules. That means $J(A) \subseteq \text{Ann}_A(M)$ by definition! I've added a line to the argument clarifying this.

Here's another proof, which is basically the same, but doesn't rely on the Artin-Wedderburn theory. Let $R$ be an Artinian ring, and let $\{I_\alpha\}$ be its set of maximal right ideals. By the descending chain property, there are finitely many maximal right ideals $\{I_1,\ldots,I_n\}$ such that
\begin{equation}
I = \bigcap_{i=1}^n I_i
\end{equation}
is contained in every $I_\alpha$. If $U_i=R/I_i$, then this means every quotient $R/I_\alpha$ (and hence every simple module) is a subquotient of $U_1\oplus\cdots\oplus U_n$. But this direct sum has an (obvious) composition series, so every simple subquotient is one of finitely many isomorphism types by the Jordan–Hölder theorem.

This is just an appendix to @Qiaochu Yuan 's nice answer that I hope could be useful (please correct me if I'm wrong).
In the notation above, since $A=F[G]$ is Artinian (as finitely generated algebra), its quotient $R=A/J(A)$ is semisimple, with $J(A)$ the Jacobson radical of $A$, which can be defined as the intersection of all maximal left ideals (i.e. maximal left submodules) of $A$. By @Qiaochu Yuan 's argument there are only finitely many simple left $R$-modules up to isomorphism. It only remains to show that any simple $A$-module is also a simple $A$-module is also a simple left $R$-module. If this is the case, we get the thesis.
To this extent, we use the following property, which is a direct consequence of the fact that for a ring $C$ (with unity) an abelian group $M$ is an $A$-module iff there is a ring homomorphism from $C$ to the group endomorphism ring of $M$.
Fact - whenever $C,D$ are rings, $M$ is a $C$-module and $\pi:C\rightarrow D$ is a ring epimorphism s.t. $ker(\pi)\subseteq Ann_C(M)$, then $M$ is also a $D$-module via $\pi$.
Now, in our case, we must show that for any simple $A$-module, $$J(A)\subseteq Ann_A(M)=\bigcap_{m\in M}Ann_A(m).$$
Where, for a subset $S\subseteq M$ we define the annihilator of $S$, denoted by $Ann_A(S)$, as: $$Ann_A(S)=\{a\in A: \forall m\in s(am=0)\}.$$
Since $M$ is simple, for any $m\in M$ we distinguish two cases:
1)-the orbit $Am$ of $m$ under the action of $A$ (i.e. the sub left-module generated by $m$) is just $\{0\}$ (this can happen only for 0 when it is fixed by $A$). Then $Ann_A(m)=A$ and the contribution to the intersection above is trivial;
2)-the submodule $Am$ is non-trivial. Then, by the simplicity of $M$ we have that $M=Am$ and we can construct an epimorphism of modules $A\rightarrow M=Am$ s.t. $a\mapsto am$. By the Fundamental Isomorphism Theorem, this induces an isomorphism of left $A$-modules $A/Ann_A(m)\cong M$. Since the proper left submodules of $A/Ann_A(m)$ correspond exactly to the left submodules (i.e. left ideals) of $A$ containing $Ann_A(m)$. So, by the simplicity of $M$, we have that $Ann_A(m)$ is a left maximal ideal of $A$.
In both cases, $J(A)\subseteq Ann_A(m)$, by definition of $J(A)$. By the arbitrariness of $m\in M$, this shows that $J(A)\subseteq Ann_A(M)$, so that we get the thesis.

Everyone seems to be working too hard:

By the Jordan-Holder theorem for modules, any simple module has a well-defined multiplicity in $F[G]$ (viewed as a left module over itself), and so there are at most $|G|= \dim_F(F[G])$ irreducible $F[G]$-modules which occur as composition factors of $F[G]$.

If $M$ is any simple (and hence nonzero) $F[G]$-module, then if $m \in M\backslash \{0\}$, the map $\varphi\colon F[G]\to M$ given by $\varphi(a)=a.m$, ($\forall a \in F[G]$), is a map of left $F[G]$-modules, and its image contains $1.m=m$ so it is non-zero. Thus as $M$ is simple, $\text{im}(\varphi)=M$ and $F[G]/\ker(\varphi)\cong M$, so that $M$ is a composition factor of $F[G]$.

Thus any irreducible has a positive multiplicity as such a composition factor of $F[G]$ and so it follows there are at most $|G|$ simple $F[G]$-modules.


This argument works for any finite-dimensional associative $F$-algebra $A$, and the bound $\dim_F(A)$ is sharp as a statement about such algebras since one can take $A = F^{\dim(A)}$.

You've skipped the part about showing $F[G]$ has a composition series in the first place (and thus the Jordan–Hölder theorem applies).
